# MYSQL: SELECT users from one user group and exclude users from another group - optimisation

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, query-optimization

I have an optimisation question here.

### Background

I have a 12000 users in a user table, on record per user. Each user can be in zero or more groups. I have a groups table with 45 groups and a groups_link table with 75000 records (to facilitate the many to many relationship).

I am making a querying screen which allows a user to filter users from the user list.

### Aim

**Specifically, I need help with:** Selecting all users that are in one group but are not in another group.

### DB Structure

[image]

### Query

My current query which runs too slowly...

```
 SELECT U.user_id,U.user_email
FROM (sc_module_users AS U)
JOIN sc_module_users_groups_links AS group_join ON group_join.user_id = U.user_id
LEFT JOIN sc_module_users_groups_links AS excluded_group_join ON group_join.user_id = U.user_id
WHERE group_join.group_id IN (27) AND excluded_group_join.group_id NOT IN (19) OR excluded_group_join.group_id IS NULL AND U.user_subscribed=1 AND U.user_active=1
GROUP BY U.user_id,U.user_id
```

This query takes 9 minutes to complete, it returns 11,000 records (out of 12,000).

Explain

Here's the explain on that query:
[image]
[Click here for a closer look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA9EW.jpg)

**Can anyone help me optimise this to below the 1 minute mark...?**

After 3 revisions, I changed it to this

```
    SELECT U.user_id,U.user_email FROM (sc_module_users AS U) WHERE ( user_country LIKE '%australia%' ) AND 
EXISTS (SELECT group_id FROM sc_module_users_groups_links l WHERE group_id in (31) AND l.user_id=U.user_id) AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT group_id FROM sc_module_users_groups_links l WHERE group_id in (27) AND l.user_id=U.user_id) 
AND U.user_subscribed=1 AND U.user_active=1 GROUP BY U.user_id
```

'
mucccch faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: removed my query suggestion but the index stuff should still apply:

The indexes on the `sc_module_users_groups_links` could be improved by creating a composite index just on `user_id` and `group_id`. The order of the columns in the index can have an impact - i believe having `user_id` first should perform better.

You could also try removing the `link_id` and just using a composite primary key since the `link_id` doesn't seem to serve any other purpose.

Comment: yeh tried running the query and had zero results. Still, using two join's seems useless, i don't know why i'm doing that now that i think about it

Comment: the two joins actually made sense after i thought about it again :)
I think the indexes are the issue because you are joining on user_id which is not the first column in any index on the group_links table

Comment: You know what, I'm using your original query with one join. I thought about it a bit more and the reason i was using two joins was because when I exclude someone from one group i still want those users who aren't in any group, realising that this was more to do with the "type" of join (ie left and not inner) i stripped it back to one "JOIN"

Comment: glad you got it working ... i don't think my second query wasn't going to do the right thing anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe the very first thing you need to do is to place parentheses:

```
// should be  
.. AND ( excluded_group_join.group_id NOT IN (19) 
  OR excluded_group_join.group_id IS NULL)  AND ....
```